# Web Api XML, How to set Encoding, Version, xmlns:xsi and xsi:schemaLocation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, xmlserializer, xml-encoding

I am using asp.net MVC4 Web Api.

I have set:

```
Dim xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter
xml.UseXmlSerializer = True
```

I have created a class that specifies the XML I need and this works well.

I am almost there but I am not sure how set the:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

and how to set the element attributes:

xmlns:xsi and xsi:schemaLocation

Can I set this using an attribute?

Answer (score 6):

This answer is one year delayed and tested for WebAPI2!

Enable XML declaration in your `WebApiConfig` class

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.WriterSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;
```

Then add `schemaLocation` property or member (I always prefer property)

```
public class SampleData
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "schemaLocation", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string SchemaLocation { get; set; }

    //other properties
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }

    public SampleData()
    {
        SchemaLocation = "http://localhost/my.xsd";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestModel 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:schemaLocation="http://localhost/my.xsd">
    <Prop1>1</Prop1>
</TestModel>
```

Comment: This solution does not work on ASP.NET MVC 4.0 and WebApi on .NET 4.0. There is no WriterSettings in it